# Analysis Sequences Proof and Tending to ∞

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The following is false. Disprove it using a counter example.

Claim: If (a<sub>n</sub>) → ∞ and b<sub>n</sub>> 0 ∀n ∈ N then (a<sub>n</sub> b<sub>n</sub>) → ∞.

Counterexample:

My attempt.

My pitiful attempt consisted of assuming b<sub>n</sub> was a sequence greater than 0. I made a<sub>n</sub> be natural numbers (the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4,...) and b<sub>n</sub> be the sequence (5, 1/n, 5, 1/n, 5, 1/n,...). Multiplied together it left (5, 1, 15, 1, 25, 1,...) which i thought answered the question as it doesn't tend to infinity.

I thought i had it, but i don't. As b<sub>n</sub> isn't in brackets it implies it is a constant from the sequence (b<sub>n</sub>), which i can choose. I don't know the sequence (b<sub>n</sub>) so it can basically be any number i presume? All i know is it's greater than 0. I can't think of a number for b<sub>n</sub> that satisfies this constraint.

Any and all help appreciated, I'm perplexed and out of ideas.

Comment: $b_n$ does **not** have to be a constant. In fact, the claim would be true in this case. However, it is only stated that $b_n$ has to be bigger zero for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Ah ok thank you, so 1/n would work??

Comment: Yes, $b_n$ can be any positive sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that $a_n=n$ and $b_n=1/n$ should work!

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much :)